# Automated Testing (Testtoolkit Test Assemblies)

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

I have an on-prem version of Business Central Wave 2 installed directly on my Windows 10 enterprise machine (NOT a docker container) and want to start writing test apps.

Firstly there is not Testtoolkit folder in the DVD but rather a Test Assemblies folder in the DVD.

Secondly, how may I import the Test Assemblies if that I what needs to be imported to start writing tests?

Answer (score 1):

The Tests and the Test Suite are on the DVD in the Folder Applications\BaseApp\Test. You can install them with the PowerShell CmdLet Publish-NAVApp (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.dynamics.nav.apps.management/publish-navapp) and Install-NAVApp (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.dynamics.nav.apps.management/install-navapp)